# How to give folder of files as input to SyntaxNet

Tags: syntaxnet

I am new to `Syntaxnet`. I followed the basic tutorial, installed syntaxnet and I modified the **`syntaxnet/demo.sh`** file and added the following code to `context.pbtxt` file:

```
input {
name: 'MAIN-IN'
record_format: 'english-text'
Part {
file_pattern:'/path_to_0095.txt'
}
}
```

This is helpful only to give the `test.txt` file as input, Now I want to give a folder of files, ex folder with 100 files as input and get it processed. I tried to give the folder as input which failed. I googled about it, but couldn't find anything useful. So Could any one please let me know how to process multiple files in a folder using syntaxnet ?

Answer (score 1):

We built a Java program around SyntaxNet that dynamically updates the context.pbtxt file with the current file name (after pulling in all of the files in the directory). I don't know if SyntaxNet will allow you to use a directory of files as input.

Comment: I am also doing the same with a python script which updates context.pbtxt. I was wondering whether i could avoid this by giving input directly to syntaxnet